# Untrained parameters affect final model performance

Tags: parameters, pytorch

I wrote some DL models in PyTorch, and fixed random seeds. Some unused functions affect the final model performance. For example, this is part of my code.

```
class StaticEmbedding(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, d_model, seq_len, mode='l'):
        super(StaticEmbedding, self).__init__()
        self.seq_len = seq_len
        self.linear_l = nn.Linear(27, seq_len)
        self.linear_d = nn.Linear(27, d_model//2)
        self.linear_p = nn.Linear(d_model//2, d_model)
        self.linear_1 = nn.Linear(27, d_model//2)
        self.linear_2 = nn.Linear(d_model//2, d_model)
        self.gelu = nn.GELU()
        self.tanh = nn.Tanh()

    def forward(self, static):  
        static = static[:,None,:]        
        if self.mode =='d':
            static = self.linear_d(static)
        elif self.mode == 'l':
            static = self.linear_l(static).transpose(1,2)
        elif self.mode == 'p':   
            static = self.linear_d(static)after this
            static = self.linear_p(self.gelu(static))
            static = self.tanh(static)
             
        return static
```

self.linear_1 & self.linear_2 is not under forward command, but I'll get different results if I remove them. I feel it's weird since they are not in the model. Can anyone explain it?

Comment: Can you please post (as an edit to the question) the example and the code you used to check that the results are different so we can reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason is you expect from randomizer more, then it could provide. Seed fixation works, if program is not principally changed, "principally" means randomizer call chain remained the same. And then you added the layers, their initialization routines break that chain.